# How to change slug before uploading to Algolia

Tags: gatsby, algolia, contentful

I'm working on implementing Algolia search into my Gatsby website. I need to format the slugs of my content correctly so that Algolia gets the correct links.

The slug my query gets from Contentful is similar to `/icon-name/`

I need it to match the path that gets created from my Gatsby-node.js file path: `/design-resources/icons/${node.slug}/`

Is it possible to get this path after its created from Gatsby-node.js or is there a way to transform the icon Query below before uploading to Algolia?

#### My Query

```
const iconQuery = `
query iconQuery {
    allContentfulIcon {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                title
                slug
                keywords
                pngFIle {
                    fluid {
                        srcSetWebp
                    }
                  }
              }
        }
    }
}`;
```

#### Transformer for Algolia

```
const queries = [
  {
    query: iconQuery,
    transformer: ({ data }) =>
      data.allContentfulIcon.edges.map(({ node }) => node), // optional
  },
];

module.exports = queries;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your `transformer`:

```
const queries = [
  {
    query: iconQuery,
    transformer: ({ data }) =>
      data.allContentfulIcon.edges.map(({ node }) => {
        node.slug = /design-resources/icons/${node.slug}/          
      
        return node;
    }),
  },
];

module.exports = queries;
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense to transform it in the transformer. When I ran this code I received this error

node.slug=`${/design-resources/icons/${node.slug}/}`
                     ^
  SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags.

I removed the brackets and it worked. this was my final code.

node.slug = `/design-resources/icons/${node.slug}/`;

Comment: Thanks @GGlass for the insights. I've updated the answer with the working final code